# Passengers who travelled recently

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image]

select distinct passenger
from table
where travel date falls in each of the last 2 months
group by passenger

When the query is run on October - September & August data should be pulled.
When run on November - September & October data should be pulled.

In the above example, "passenger 1" should be pulled because he travelled both in the month of August and September. "passenger 2&3" should not be pulled.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Stack Overflow won't write your entire solution for you. See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (Tangentially, since this appears on its surface to be a homework/coursework question, please consider the academic integrity implications of posting your assignments without demonstrating a good-faith effort in solving the question prior.)

Comment: @esqew
Below is what I tried, 
select distinct passenger, travel date
    from table
    where travel date >= dateadd('month', -2, date_trunc('month', sysdate))
    and travel date < sysdate
group by passenger, travel date

This gave me results of anyone who travelled in the last 2 months but not each month

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name redshift trial. Will tag this as well hereafter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use `date_trunc()` for the date filtering.  Then:

```
select t.passenger
from t
where travel_date >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '2 month' and
      travel_date < date_trunc('month', current_date)
group by t.passenger
having count(distinct date_trunc('month', travel_date)) = 2;
```

This uses `count(distinct)` because it is generalizable.  For instance, it is easy to adjust this query for people who have traveled in four out of the last 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

I have understood your requirements as **Select the Passengers who traveled at least once in every month of the last two months (from Today) excluding the travels of the Current Month**.

The required SQL code:

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT passenger AS passenger
        ,MONTH(travel_date) AS travel_month
        ,COUNT(*) AS number_of_travels
    FROM [dbo].[tblTravels]
    WHERE DATEDIFF(month, travel_date, GETDATE()) <= 2
        AND MONTH(travel_date) != MONTH(GETDATE())
    GROUP BY passenger
        ,MONTH(travel_date)
    )
SELECT passenger
FROM cte
GROUP BY passenger
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

***More Explanation about answer*** :
To get the Last Two months From Today excluding the Current Month

```
DATEDIFF(month, travel_date, GETDATE()) <= 2
        AND MONTH(travel_date) != MONTH(GETDATE())
```

***If you would like to verify the Code, simply Run the following script:***

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTravels] (
    [passenger] [int] NULL
    ,[travel_date] [datetime] NULL
    ,[travel_id] [nchar](10) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblTravels]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblTravels] VALUES (1, '2020-08-01', 'a')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblTravels] VALUES (1, '2020-09-01', 'a')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblTravels] VALUES (2, '2020-08-01', 'a')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblTravels] VALUES (3, '2020-09-01', 'a')
GO

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tblTravels]
GO

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT passenger AS passenger
        ,MONTH(travel_date) AS travel_month
        ,COUNT(*) AS number_of_travels
    FROM [dbo].[tblTravels]
    WHERE DATEDIFF(month, travel_date, GETDATE()) <= 2
        AND MONTH(travel_date) != MONTH(GETDATE())
    GROUP BY passenger
        ,MONTH(travel_date)
    )
SELECT passenger
FROM cte
GROUP BY passenger
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

DROP TABLE [dbo].[tblTravels]
```

Answer (score 0):

use below query

```
Select passenger FROM travel
WHERE  DATEDIFF(month, travel_date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<=2
group BY passenger
```

for get current date can use **getdate()** or **current_timestamp**.
and if you want total detail you dont must from group by.

```
Select passenger,travel_date,travel_id FROM travel
WHERE  DATEDIFF(month, travel_data, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<=2
order by passenger
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. <=2 will this give the details of who travelled in each of the last 2 months? I believe, this will give only who travelled in the last months